# specific Regular expression search python

Tags: python, regex

This is my first post. 
I always come to this forum looking for an answer when it comes to code.

I have been fighting with understanding regular expressions in Python, but it is kind of hard.

I have text that looks like this:

```
Name:   Clash1
Distance:   -1.341m
Image Location: Test 1_navis_files\cd000001.jpg
HardStatus: New
Clash Point:    3.884m, -2.474m, 2.659m
Date Created:   2016/6/2422:45:09

Item 1
GUID:   6efaec51-b699-4d5a-b947-505a69c31d52
Path:   File ->Colisiones_v2015.dwfx ->Segment ->Pipes (1) ->Pipe Types (1) ->Default (1) ->Pipe Types [2463] ->Shell
Item Name:  Pipe Types [2463]
Item Type:  Shell

Item 2
GUID:   6efaec51-b699-4d5a-b947-505a69c31dea
Path:   File ->Colisiones_v2015.dwfx ->Segment ->Walls (4) ->Basic Wall (4) ->Wall 1 (4) ->Basic Wall [2343] ->Shell
Item Name:  Basic Wall [2343]
Item Type:  Shell

------------------


Name:   Clash2
Distance:   -1.341m
Image Location: Test 1_navis_files\cd000002.jpg
HardStatus: New
Clash Point:    3.884m, 3.533m, 2.659m
Date Created:   2016/6/2422:45:09

Item 1
GUID:   6efaec51-b699-4d5a-b947-505a69c31d52
Path:   File ->Colisiones_v2015.dwfx ->Segment ->Pipes (1) ->Pipe Types (1) ->Default (1) ->Pipe Types [2463] ->Shell
Item Name:  Pipe Types [2463]
Item Type:  Shell

Item 2
GUID:   6efaec51-b699-4d5a-b947-505a69c31de8
Path:   File ->Colisiones_v2015.dwfx ->Segment ->Walls (4) ->Basic Wall (4) ->Wall 1 (4) ->Basic Wall [2341] ->Shell
Item Name:  Basic Wall [2341]
Item Type:  Shell

------------------
```

What I need to do is to create a list that extracts for every chunk of text (separated by the `-------------------------------`) the following things as a string: the clash name and the clash point.

For example: `Clash 1 3.884, 3.533, 2.659`

I am really new to Python, and really do not have much understanding about regular expressions.

Can anyone give me some clues about using regex to extract this values from the text?

I did something like this:

```
exp = r'(?<=Clash Point\s)(?<=Point\s)([0-9]*)'
match = re.findall(exp, html)

if match:
    OUT.append(match)
else:
    OUT = 'fail'
```

but I know I am far from my goal.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a regex solution, you could come up with:

```
^Name:\s*         # look for Name:, followed by whitespaces
                  # at the beginning of a line
(?P<name>.+)      # capture the rest of the line
                  # in a group called "name"
[\s\S]+?          # anything afterwards lazily
^Clash\ Point:\s* # same construct as above
(?P<point>.+)     # same as the other group
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/eP4zP6/1).

---

Translated into `Python` code, this would be:

```
import re
rx = re.compile(r"""
                ^Name:\s*
                (?P<name>.+)
                [\s\S]+?
                ^Clash\ Point:\s*
                (?P<point>.+)""", re.VERBOSE|re.MULTILINE)

for match in rx.finditer(your_string_here):
    print match.group('name')
    print match.group('point')
```

This will output:

```
Clash1
3.884m, -2.474m, 2.659m
Clash2
3.884m, 3.533m, 2.659m
```

See [**a working demo on ideone.com**](http://ideone.com/o1kuJ4).

Answer (score 0):

```
import re


lines = s.split('\n')

names = []
points = []

for line in lines:    
    result = re.search('^Name:\s*(\w+)', line)
    if result:
        names.append(result.group(1))

    result = re.search('^Clash Point:\s*([-0-9m., ]+)',line)
    if result:
        points.append(result.group(1))

print(names)
print(points)

# if you need more nice output, you can use zip() function
for name, point in zip(names, points):
    print(name, point)
```

You can find useful information about regular expressions at regexr.com. Also, i use it for quick tests and reference.